# How can I send URLstring as get params in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want send a "URL" as get params in AngularJS.

===

success:

```
example.com/purchase/loremipsum
```

failed(redirect to otherwise):

```
example.com/purchase/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

==

javascript

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
        controller: 'galleryCtrl'
      }).
      when('/purchase/:url', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/purchase.html',
        controller: 'PurchaseCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('GalleryCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams, $modal, $log, $location){
  $http.get(url).
  success(function(data){
    $scope.itemUrl = encodeURIComponent(data.url);
  });
});    

app.controller('PurchaseCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams, $modal, $log, $location){
  $scope.url = $routeParams.url;
  alert($scope.log);
});
```

gallery.html

```
<a ng-href="#/purchase/{{itemUrl}}">BUY</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

%2F will be converted into a '/'

That means angular will try to find match for example.com/purchase/http://www.google.com, which doesn't match your pattern '/purchase/:url'